# Project management tool that bubbles up from employee to CEO

Tags: team-management, tools

Few days ago, I encountered a new tool that in essence makes people write 5-minute reports every week/month, of which their managers send the important things up to their managers and so on and so forth up untill the CEO.

Does anybody know the name and website? I can't stand that I forgot what it was... :s

Is a tool like that actually beneficial for a project manager?

Comment: Can you share a bit more information? I felt like a human google, and in order to help out I need more information. Where you looking for something? Did somebody show it to you? Is there a good reference in your browser history?

Comment: I've been looking through my browser history, but found no hits... It was a comment by someone 'somewhere' on a forum. I've also been trying Google as well, and came here as a last resort. I hoped someone might know the tool that I'm talking about... No need to Google it for me, but if you know of such a tool, that'd be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Was this it?

http://15five.com/

Interesting idea, but in asking EACH employee to do this, then every for 12 employees on a team, the manager has to spend an hour reading the reports, then distilling information. Has some benefits, but could get unwieldy for some depending on number of direct reports.

Comment: Yep, that was it, thanks so much! :-) I agree that the tool has drawbacks, and I would insist that people only write reports if they've something to tell. It's a waste of time to make this stuff mandatory...

Comment: Nice finding Trevor

Answer (score 0):

Interesting comment on this type of functionality on Manager Tools Blog

[This is not Communication](http://www.manager-tools.com/2012/05/not-communication)

Comment: Very true article. Relations are about trust, confidence and happiness. No online tool can give you that. Still, it is useful as an *addition* to personal relationships. Written ideas are not forgotten. And it solve the problem that noone can talk face-to-face with everybody: yet if things are written down, the reach is much wider. And look at the internet: so many non-personal information, but useful nonetheless!